# Using application.xml instead of ejb-jar.xml

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, ear

I have a project that contain many ejb-module, each has it is own ejb-jar.xml.
All of these module  are packaged in a single ear.
i need to centralize my deployment descriptor in one file,
can i use the application.xml for that issue? can i use ejb-jar.xml in the ear ? or is there other solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, not in an EAR. Each jar with EJB:s is his own separate module. If you cannot describe through annotations all the things you want to describe, then resort to the ejb-jar.xml file and put him in the sacred META-INF directory of the jar file that contains the beans. The application.xml file is mostly for describing things that is true for the entire application, environment entries being one thing that immediately comes to mind. Separation of modules and separation of ejb-jar.xml also separates the namespace and makes it possible for you to have multiple beans and environment entries defined with the same name without any clashes.

If you don't need this modularization, then it is possible for you to package everything in a WAR file instead and use only one ejb-jar.xml file for the application, put in the WEB-INF directory. In fact, would you first package your beans in a jar file together with an ejb-jar.xml file that you throw into a subdirectory called lib in your WAR file,  then these descriptors (the XML files) will be ignored.